# Android Studio add jar gives error

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to add `nineoldandroid.jar` and when I run the project it gives this error:

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CustomProject:compileDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I can't understand what I'm doing!